# CNN for 5 Classifications: ValueError: Shapes (None, 228, 228, 1) and (None, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So I am building a CNN to identify 5 different classifications/diseases of images. I am pretty sure, I may have done something wrong with my one-hot encoding...or creating of my train_y label values, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated! I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 228, 228, 1) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Here is my code:

```
DATADIR = "/Users/...pathname"
CATEGORIES = ["disease0", "disease1", "disease2", "disease3", "non_disease"]

training_data = []
IMG_SIZE = 228 #for resizing the image, but need to find the right size for this, (5472,3648) is original image size

def creating_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)  # gets us into the path for 5 diseases directory
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category) #assign one hot encoding to each disease.. [1,0,0,0,0]
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert images to an array, IMREAD_COLOR for rgb
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) #would be (5472,3648) at full size. INTER_AREA for shrinking an image
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num]) #would be img_array if not resizing
            except Exception as e:
                pass
creating_training_data() #calling the function

random.shuffle(training_data) #shuffling the data

#for sample in training_data[:10]:
    #print(sample[1])

train_X = [] #packing shuffled data into the variables we will use right before feeding it to neural network
train_y = [] # could also put validation set here

for features, label in training_data: #building out lists for features and labels
    train_X.append(features)
    train_y.append(label)

#convert train_X into a numpy array
train_X = np.array(train_X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) #-1 is how many features do we have..catch all for anything, any number. 3 is for RGB. 1 for grey

#normalize the data by scaling...for pixel data min is 0 and max is 255
train_X = train_X/255.0  #may need to use keras.utils.normalize to perform this instead

print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
#Creating our CNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=train_X.shape[1:])) #skip the -1...using the shape of the data (228,228,1)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) # Now we have a 2x64 CNN

model.add(Flatten()) #Flatten the data because Convolutional is 2D whereas the dense layer wants a 1D data set
model.add(Dense(64))

#Adding Output Layer
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])

model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=5, epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Note: When I check the shape for train_X and train_y ,
they both are: (4181, 228, 228, 1)

Comment: My data is all labeled photos sized (5472,3648) and I have them in labeled subfolder. I am shrinking their size for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're training your model to predict 5 classes though in this line:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

You specified the last softmax layer to predict only one class, you should make the last softmax layer match the number of classes you want to predict.

Edit regarding the labelling of data:

```
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Since you're training the model to predict 5 classes, and your data is labelled as 5 classes.

Regarding the labeling list try something like this:

```
DATADIR = "/Users/...pathname"
CATEGORIES = ["disease0", "disease1", "disease2", "disease3", "non_disease"]

train_x = []
train_y = []
IMG_SIZE = 228 #for resizing the image, but need to find the right size for this, (5472,3648) is original image size

def creating_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        labels = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)  # gets us into the path for 5 diseases directory
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category) #assign one hot encoding to each disease.. [1,0,0,0,0]
        labels[class_num] = 1
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert images to an array, IMREAD_COLOR for rgb
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) #would be (5472,3648) at full size. INTER_AREA for shrinking an image
                train_x.append(new_array) #would be img_array if not resizing
                train_y.append(labels)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
train_X = np.array(train_X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
train_X = train_X/255.0  #may need to use keras.utils.normalize to perform this instead

print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
#Creating our CNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=train_X.shape[1:])) #skip the -1...using the shape of the data (228,228,1)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) # Now we have a 2x64 CNN

model.add(Flatten()) #Flatten the data because Convolutional is 2D whereas the dense layer wants a 1D data set
model.add(Dense(64))

#Adding Output Layer
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=5, epochs=10,validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223901/discussion-on-answer-by-mina-abd-el-massih-cnn-for-5-classifications-valueerror).